# Problem with getting key of type with a generic type

Tags: typescript

[TypeScript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIHkBmAVcEA8KA0UBqAfFALxQDW8A9klAN4BQUTUA2gApQCWAduVTSigBDAM5QU7ALpQIAD2ARuAEzF4A-FDYAuKNwgA3CACdJOodxD0AvgG569UJHEQRwEnUbMhO7gFcAtgBGxnbMUIE+AcFGocwAxjquRjwA5rFMSonAydxp1vZxlNyuUCkQwHCIqC5upAAUAJQ6lchokFg1uH5BxkTERAxhAPQAVCOezCNQAMLmwgA2IpRQRuW+RrwA5IGb4b5uq8Dr3KlQcVCURlBKUADunPPzKy6+8248wrzGRpfCIhNMKbAAAWLmgQlWukobmoUEc0AABt1ogiAVARkMAYdjlBNkJNnZbAUiiUyhV4MgAOKKYycc6kLAyeSKFTOVwERrNCmodBYLpRXokAZYtYbXH4wl2eiFYpuMkASQU-la6AAcgKrgzBHIFMoxCgahzOEqdCgmroNUKuEqAHRCGxAA)

I've got a utility type that returns keys that have a value of a specific type

```
type KeyOfType<T, V> = keyof {
    [P in keyof T as T[P] extends V? P: never]: any
};
```

This has been working great up to now when used without any generic types. For example

```
type Test = {
    a: number;
    b: number;
    c: string;
    d: string;
}

const getKeyOfTest = (): KeyOfType<Test, number> => {
    /**
     * Can also return 'b' but returning c or d will result in an error as
     * these are not of type `number`
     */
    return 'a';
};
```

As soon as I introduce a generic type I start running into problems

```
const getKeyOfGeneric = <T extends Test>(): KeyOfType<T, number> => {
    return 'a';
};
```

For which I get the following error

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof { [P in keyof T as T[P] extends number ? P : never]: any; }'.
  Type '"a"' is not assignable to type '(T[P] extends number ? P : never) | (T["a"] extends number ? "a" : never) | (T["b"] extends number ? "b" : never) | (T["c"] extends number ? "c" : never) | (T["d"] extends number ? "d" : never)'.ts(2322)
```

I don't understand this error as my thinking is that if `T extends Test` then the compiler should know that the key `a` is of type `number`

Using TS version 4.8.2. Also happening in version 5.3.2

Comment: Why not just use `KeyOfType<Test, number>` that is what the function returns. You can't assign concrete value to types with generic parameters, since the generic parameter can't be resolved.

Comment: You can write your own custom `KeyOfT<T, V>` operator with conditional types that works for *specific* `T`, but the compiler doesn't "understand" what it does for *generic* `T`; it can't abstract over the definition to derive invariants. (i.e., Your intuition about what the compiler should "know" is mistaken.)  Really, TS should probably support a *native* operator as per [ms/TS#48992](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48992), and then such reasoning could be part of the implementation. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what's missing?

Comment: @jcalz It might address the question but to be honest I don't really know. The answer seems to be "it can't be done" which is fine but I'm not clear on why considering something like this works as I expect it to

`const getItemOfTypeNumber = <T extends Test>(item: T): number => item.a;`. Here the compiler "knows" that the key `a` returns a value of type `number` but seems unaware in the `getKeyOfGeneric` function

Comment: The answer to what question is “it can’t be done”? The question as asked seems to be about why there’s an error, which is covered by ms/TS#48992 as linked above. If there’s something specific you’re asking which isn’t just “why isn’t this working” so you want to [edit] the post to make that clear?